# Move rigidbody from point a to b

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to move an instantiation of a rigidbody2d(Ship) from one point to another.
Shippos is my point a.
Targetpos is my point b.
They are assigned in the inspector,
The instantiation is triggered by a mouse click on object,
My problem is i can't figure out the right function to use ,Or where to put it
to be able to move my instance ,Or how to control the speed of the movement.

```
public class Attack : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform ShipPos;
public Transform Targetpos;
public Timer temp;
public Rigidbody2D ship;
public float speed = 4;
public float step; 

void start(){

}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


}
void OnMouseDown(){

    step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        temp.timeleft /= 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.timeleft; i++) {
            Rigidbody2D shipinstance;
            shipinstance = Instantiate (ship, ShipPos.position, ShipPos.rotation) as Rigidbody2D;

        }



}
```

}

Comment: Start a coroutine when the button is pressed then pass that instantiated object to the `moveToX` function in the duplicate.

Comment: i can't put the instance in the other function out of scope

Comment: `Transform obj  = Instantiate (ship, ShipPos.position, ShipPos.rotation) as Rigidbody2D;` then pass `obj` to the function:  `StartCoroutine(moveToX(obj , pointB, 1.0f));` Nothing complicated here.

Comment: I tried it and it worked but only for one of my instance how can i make them all move at the same time(i make more than one instance at a press)

Comment: Remove the `isMoving` variable and any code that uses it in that function